# Use AngularJS in chrome extension with object using JQuery Deferred

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-extension, angularjs-scope

I'm completely new to angular, and I'm trying to get it to work in the context of a simple chrome extension (a simple rss feed reader) I'm trying to write.

The problem is that I already have a couple of javascript objects that handle the feed info, but those objects make use of JQuery Deferred implementation.

As far as I understand I can still use those objects if I use the $scope.$apply() function to make Angular aware that some change happened, but I can't get it to work.

These are my template and controller files:

**Popup.html**

```
<html ng-app="app" ng-csp>
<head>
    <script src="lib/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>


    <script src="js/utilities.js"></script>
    <script src="js/options/Options.js"></script>
    <script src="js/options/Feed.js"></script>
    <script src="js/options/FeedList.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/popup.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/chromeStorage.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/rssListCtrl.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="RssListCtrl">
    <p>{{title}}</p>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="feed in feedList">
            {{feed.name}}
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="item in feed.items">
                    <a href="{{item.link}}" target="_blank">{{item.title}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <button ng-click="check()">check</button>
</body>
```

**RssListCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('RssListCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.feedList = FeedList().load().done(function(feedList) {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.feedList = feedList;
        });
    });

    $scope.check = function () {
        console.log($scope.feedList);
    }

});
```

I added the button to check in the console if the data loaded correctly. The strange thing is that, when I press the button, I get the correct output in the console AND the template in the chrome popup updates correctly with the loaded data.

I suppose I'm missing something (probably stupid), but I can't see it. Any help?

**Update**: the console for the popup doesn't show any error and I used the ng-csp

Comment: Rightclick the popup, Inspect, check the console, debug the code. A random guess: might be something like [AngularJS uses eval in chrome extension](//stackoverflow.com/q/25503213)

Comment: Already did that, the console doesn't show any error and I already included the ng-csp attribute to the html tag

Comment: @Antiphon0x on the button that logs the data afterwards did you use ng-click to trigger the handler?  Just asking because ng-click also triggers an $apply call... this is strange though.

Comment: Setting `$scope.feedList` to a [jQuery Deferred](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)  object and then having the callback replace it with data is dubious code.

Comment: I did use ng-click, that could explain why the view is updating even if the click callback doesn't update the scope.

Comment: @georgeawg I know, but the returned by the callback is the same object assigned initially... I did that because I'm trying to use the jquery deferred based object in angular

Comment: I recommend that you replace the jQuery Defered objects with [AngularJS $q.defer()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-deferred-api) objects and their respective promises which are integrated with the AngularJS framework and its digest cycle.

Comment: See  [JavaScript Promises and why jQuery Implemetation is Broken](https://thewayofcode.wordpress.com/2013/01/22/javascript-promises-and-why-jquery-implementation-is-broken/). AngularJS promises respect the [Promises/A+ specification](https://promisesaplus.com/) and are implemented correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use [$q.when](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#when) to convert the jQuery Deferred object to an AngularJS promise:

```
app.controller('RssListCtrl', function ($scope, $q) {

    var feedListPromise = $q.when(FeedList().load());

    feedListPromise.then(function(feedList)
        $scope.feedList = feedList;
    });

    $scope.check = function () {
        console.log($scope.feedList);
    }

});
```

AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

The [AngularJS $q Service $q.when Method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#when) creates an AngularJS promise that is integrated with the AngularJS execution context and its digest cycle.

> ### $q.when
>
> Wraps an object that might be a value or a (3rd party) then-able promise into a $q promise. This is useful when you are dealing with an object that might or might not be a promise, or if the promise comes from a source that can't be trusted.
>
> [— AngularJS $q Service API Reference ($q.when)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#when)

See also,

- [JavaScript Promises and why jQuery Implemetation is Broken](https://thewayofcode.wordpress.com/2013/01/22/javascript-promises-and-why-jquery-implementation-is-broken/)
- [Promises/A+ specification](https://promisesaplus.com/)

Comment: tank you for the interesting links, I didn't know about those implementation details about jQuery promises. Your suggestion looks like what I'm looking for ("translate" from jQuery to Angular promise), but it doesn't seems to work... the view still doesn't update when the $q.when() promise is fulfilled